# Transpose a square matrix code

Tags: matrices, applications

I know it's not programming area , but I think it's more related to math.

I have the following function:

```
public void transpose()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i ; ++j) {
                double tmpJI = get(j, i);
                put(j, i, get(i, j));
                put(i, j, tmpJI);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or in plain english, suppose matrix size = matix's number rows = matrix's num cols.

---

from $i = 0 $ to $size$ do:

--> for $j = 0$ to $i$ do:

-----> replace $mat_{i,j}$ with $mat_{j,i}$

--> make $j$ bigger in 1

make $i$ bigger in 1.

---

For the following matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        5 & 1 & 0 \\
        6 & 5 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}$$

the transpose output is:

$$\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 6 \\
        5 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 5 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}$$

when the correct transpose is:

$$\begin{matrix}
        1 & 5 & 6 \\
        0 & 1 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}$$

What is my problem?

Comment: You have to use a temporary variable to store the value of $a_{ij}$. Assign $a_{ji}$ to $a_{ij}$ and then assign the temporary variable to $a_{ji}$.

Comment: @GTXOC same problem

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515424/transpose-a-nxn-matrix?

Comment: I do not know Java or C++ or the like very well, but I would write a function printing the indices that the two for loops produce.. Maybe they are not running over the proper indices?

Comment: That code looks right to me. Check your get() and put() functions, and in particular, that your rows/columns are zero-indexed.

Comment: @lhf It's not, but they're not solved my problem.

Comment: The code looks right, the assumptions seem correct, but what happens if you use `for (j=i; j< mat_size; j++)` instead?

Comment: Code looks good to me too: maybe there's a problem in the code you haven't posted @user1798362. Which languse is it? If you put up the rest of the code needed, I or someone else might be able to debug it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your transpose method: I've just added the code I've written to my answer which proves this. It incorporates your transpose method. Run it and God willing, you'll see the result is correct. There must be / have been an error elsewhere in your code. @user1798362

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just implemented the code in Java (adding the necessary code to feed in the matrix you gave as an example, implement the get and put methods and print the results) and it works fine for me, so there must be a problem elsewhere in your code. I've put my code below. It's not textbook, but it proves the point: there's nothing wrong with your transpose method. Run it and God permitting, you'll see that.

```
// program which transposes a matrix M and prints M and its transpose

public class Matrix {

    double[][] M = new double[3][3];

    static int mat_size=3;

    public Matrix()
    {
        M[0][0]=1;
        M[0][1]=0;
        M[0][2]=0;
        M[1][0]=5;
        M[1][1]=1;
        M[1][2]=0;
        M[2][0]=6;
        M[2][1]=5;
        M[2][2]=1;

        System.out.println("M");

        printMatrix();

        transpose();

        System.out.println("M'");

        printMatrix();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Matrix();

    }

    public void transpose()
    {
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i ; ++j) {
                double tmpJI = get(j, i);
                put(j, i, get(i, j));
                put(i, j, tmpJI);
            }
        }
    }



    public void printMatrix()
    {

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mat_size ; ++j) {
                System.out.print((int)get(i,j)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private void put(int i, int j, double d) {

        M[i][j]=d;

    }

    private double get(int i, int j) 

        return M[i][j];

    }

}
```